# remember all values in an array using cookies - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

i want to be able to remember all values in an array using cookies, but do not know how. I am also using js-cookies.

```
 Here is my code:
 var usernames = new Array();
 var input = $('#input').val();
 usernames.push(input);
 // each time something is inputted, it'll be saved to the
 // array usernames. I want it so that when refreshed, all
 // of the inputs remain in 'usernames'
 alert(usernames);
```

Comment: To save cookies use `Cookies.set('users', JSON.stringify(usernames));` and to load use `usernames = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('users'));`

Comment: Why cookies? They inflate the size of the HTTP requests and responses unnecessarily. Look at [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) instead, which is almost universally supported (and easy to use without a lib).

Comment: @charlietfl he said that he use js-cookies.

Comment: @jcubic my bad...missed that

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a better place to store this data, but using cookies follows the same steps, just need to get a [set/get method for Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework). First you need to see if there is a value. If there is you need to parse it. After you update the array, you need to convert the value to a string and store it.

```
//Read local storage to see if we have anything saved
var lsUserNames = localStorage.getItem("usernames");
//Get the usernames array
var usernames = lsUserNames ? JSON.parse(lsUserNames) : [];

//Just using prompt to get the username instead of making form
var uname = window.prompt("Enter Name");
if(uname) usernames.push(uname);

//set the updated array to local storage
localStorage.setItem("usernames", JSON.stringify(usernames));
console.log(usernames.join());
```